# Need to sort 4 different arrays based on the sorting of a separate array

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, csv, indexing

I am looking to populate several arrays based on data pulled out from a CSV file.

Right now in my script, I read the file line-by-line and pull out each column I need and place it into a separate array (eg. server hostname goes into a @server array, capacity information goes into a @capacity array, etc.)

After the arrays are populated, I print them out using a simple for loop like

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @server; $i++)
{
    #print different arrays by using $i for the key
}
```

Currently this works because in the loop where I store all the information into the arrays, it is done linearly so each array index matches information in the other arrays.

However, I now have need to sort the information by server, in the @server array. What I would like to do is alphabetically sort the @server array, but have each index in the other arrays that (before sorting) matches also get sorted identically.

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile now, going between hashes and multi-dimensional arrays, and add to this the fact that I am relatively new to Perl, this is all becoming very difficult for me.

Below is the code I am using to pull information out of the CSV file. I am aware of the Text::CSV module, however installing additional modules is not available to me.

```
while (my $line = <INFILE>)
{
    chomp($line);
    if (index($line, "ONSITE") == -1 && index($line, "IBM3584") != -1)
    my @separated = split(',', $line);
    if ($separated[4] > 0)
    {
        push (@server, $separated[0]);
        push (@slot, $separated[7]);
        push (@volume, $separated[1]);
        push (@used, $separated[8]);
        push (@pool, $separated[3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your data structures as they are, you can sort by index

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@fruit, @line, @color);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split ',';
    push @fruit, $cols[0];
    push @line, $cols[1];
    push @color, $cols[2];
}

for my $index (sort {$fruit[$a] cmp $fruit[$b]} (0..$#fruit)) {
    printf "%-12s %-8s %s\n", $fruit[$index], $line[$index], $color[$index];
}

__DATA__
apple,line 1,red
orange,line 2,orange
pear,line 3,green
strawberry,line 4,red
banana,line 5,yellow
kiwi,line 6,greyish green
```

Outputs:

```
apple        line 1   red
banana       line 5   yellow
kiwi         line 6   greyish green
orange       line 2   orange
pear         line 3   green
strawberry   line 4   red
```

However, if it makes sense to keep your data grouped together, I would advise using an array of hashes instead:

```
my @records;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split ',';
    push @records, {
        fruit => $col[0],
        line  => $col[1],
        color => $col[2],
    };
}

for my $record (sort {$a->{fruit} cmp $b->{fruit}} @records) {
    printf "%-12s %-8s %s\n", @{$record}{qw(fruit line color)};
}
```

Comment: +1: AoH is probably the best way to go!! Nifty use of hash slice too (show-off!)

Comment: This seems like it is a very clean option and the one that I would like to use. I'll try it out and let you know if I have any questions or comments. Thanks!

Comment: WOW. This works AMAZING!! Not to mention it looks so much cleaner than what I was trying to hack together. If you can, can you explain the first line of the for loop? More specifically what it is doing within the sort?

Comment: @MikeRinehart Since you have constructed `array of hashes` it is sorting using string comparison operator (`cmp`) on values referenced by `fruit` key. add `use Data::Dumper;` and `print Dumper \@records;` before your `for loop` to see your data structure. That will help.

Comment: @MikeRinehart I'm glad we found a solution that works for you.  I could try to explain what [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) is doing in that line, but honestly you're likely to get a lot further by studying the docs.  There are examples of sorting based off a hash value.  Additionally, of an AoH (Array of hashes) is unfamiliar, I'd recommend checking out the [Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the indexes of the `@server` array, then arrange each of the arrays by the sorted indexes:

```
my @indexes = sort { $server[$a] cmp $server[$b] } 0 .. $#servers;

@servers  = @servers[@indexes];
@capacity = @capacity[@indexes];
# etc.
```

But in general you might want to look into the idea of putting hashes into an array, eg:

```
@servers = (
    { name => 'foo', capacity => 'whatever', ... },
    # ...
);

@servers = sort { $a->{name} cmp $b->{name} } @servers;
```